# Sent Matic (ERC-20) from Metamask on Ethereum Main Network to Bybit Matic Address but tokens got lost

Tags: metamask, polygon

I lost the tokens in this transaction, though it was successful on etherscan. Is this because I sent Matic on the Ethereum Network? The Bybit Matic address is an 0x adress and seeems to accept ERC-20 tokens.

thanks in advance

0x8be927a733bccb3ab29c17f79e53ad9b88f393a65c176b93da2ff10fcc06067a

transaction hash^

Comment: Please provide additional details: this is the address to deposit eth on Bybit? Have you tried reaching to their customer support, it looks like it's an address which has been dealing with eth in the past

Comment: It should be the matic address from Bybit. I clicked into Matic and copy and pasted that address. I will contact their support team.